# Scrapy get information about the SSL certificate

Tags: scrapy

I was wondering how it is possible to get information of a pages SSL certificate, using Scrapy.
Is there a method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy 2.0.0 introduced [Response.certificate](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.certificate).